React prop is passed as a function but is not recognized as such
I have an issue with the interaction between some React bar charts and a onClick call-back function that does not get recognized as such.
I have two react chart components: "WeeklyBarkChart" and "HourlyBarkChart" with a parent "BarkChartsContainer".
There is a weekly bar chart, with all barking occurrences per week. Each bar represents a week. When I click on a bar, a function get called, and a second graph component (HourlyBarkChart) gets notified with the props selectedDate, SelectedCase and call-back onHourSelect. That callback gets passed as "undefined", even as I have defined it as a callback in the parent component.
From the browser F12-console:
When I click a bar in Weekly:
HourlyBarkChart props:
{selectedDate: '2024-07-15', selectedCase: 'C113-877-122', onHourSelect: undefined}
When I click a bar in Hourly:
￼HourlyBarkChart.tsx:38 Bar clicked in HourlyBarkChart: 2024-07-17 11:00
￼HourlyBarkChart.tsx:39 Is onHourSelect a function? false (my own console.log message)
￼intercept-console-error.ts:46 onHourSelect is not defined as a function
parent component:
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import WeeklyBarkChart from './WeeklyBarkChart';
import HourlyBarkChart from './HourlyBarkChart';
import MinuteBarkChart from './MinuteBarkChart';

const BarkChartsContainer = () => {
  const [caseIds, setCaseIds] = useState<string[]>([]);
  const [selectedCase, setSelectedCase] = useState<string | null>('C690774');
  const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState<string | null>(null);
  const [selectedDateHour, setSelectedDateHour] = useState<string | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchCaseIds = async () => {
      try {
    const response = await fetch('/api/cases');
    const data = await response.json();
    setCaseIds(data.caseIds || []);
      } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching case IDs:', error);
      }
    };
    fetchCaseIds();
  }, []);

  const handleCaseChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
    setSelectedCase(event.target.value);
    setSelectedDate(null);
    setSelectedDateHour(null);
  };

  const handleWeekSelect = (startDate: string) => {
    setSelectedDate(startDate);
    setSelectedDateHour(null);
  };

  const handleHourSelect = (dateHour: string) => {
    console.log('handleHourSelect is defined:', typeof handleHourSelect === 'function');
    console.log('Hour selected in BarkChartsContainer:', dateHour);
    setSelectedDateHour(dateHour);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="dropdown-container">
    <label htmlFor="caseDropdown">Select Case ID: </label>
    <select id="caseDropdown" onChange={handleCaseChange} value={selectedCase || ''}>
      <option value="" disabled>Select a case</option>
      {caseIds.map((caseId) => (
        <option key={caseId} value={caseId}>
          {caseId}
        </option>
      ))}
    </select>
      </div>

      {selectedCase && (
    <WeeklyBarkChart 
    selectedCase={selectedCase} 
    onWeekSelect={handleWeekSelect}  // Pass the callback
    />
      )}
    {selectedDate && selectedCase && (
    <HourlyBarkChart 
      selectedCase={selectedCase} 
      selectedDate={selectedDate} 
      onHourSelect={handleHourSelect}  // Pass the callback
    />
      )}
      {selectedDateHour && selectedCase && (
    <MinuteBarkChart selectedCase={selectedCase} selectedDateHour={selectedDateHour} />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default BarkChartsContainer;

--------------------------
Hourly chart:

import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { BarChart, Bar, XAxis, YAxis, CartesianGrid, Tooltip, ResponsiveContainer } from 'recharts';

interface BarkData {
  date_hour: string;
  number_of_barks: number;
}

interface HourlyBarkChartProps {
  selectedDate: string;
  selectedCase: string;
  onHourSelect: (hour: string) => void; 
}

const fetchBarkData = async (startDate: string, caseId: string): Promise<BarkData[]> => {
  const response = await fetch(`/api/hourlyBarks?startDate=${startDate}&caseId=${caseId}`);
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error('Failed to fetch bark data');
  }
  const data = await response.json();
  return data.data;
};

const HourlyBarkChart: React.FC<HourlyBarkChartProps> = ({ selectedDate, selectedCase, onHourSelect }) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState<BarkData[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const barkData = await fetchBarkData(selectedDate, selectedCase);
      setData(barkData);
    };
    fetchData();
    console.log("UseEffect called")
  }, [selectedDate, selectedCase]);

  const handleBarClick = (event: any) => {
    if (event?.activePayload?.[0]?.payload?.date_hour) {
      const hour = event.activePayload[0].payload.date_hour;
      console.log('Bar clicked in HourlyBarkChart:', hour);
      console.log('Is onHourSelect a function?', typeof onHourSelect === 'function');
      if (typeof onHourSelect === 'function') {
    onHourSelect(hour); // Call the function directly
      } else {
    console.error('onHourSelect is not defined as a function');
      }
    } else {
      console.log('Condition not met for bar click');
    }
  };

  console.log('HourlyBarkChart props:', { selectedDate, selectedCase, onHourSelect });


  return (
    <div className="bg-white rounded-lg p-4 h-full">
      <h1 className="text-lg font-semibold">Hourly Barks</h1>
      <ResponsiveContainer width="100%" height="80%">
    <BarChart data={data} onClick={handleBarClick}>
      <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
      <XAxis dataKey="date_hour" />
      <YAxis />
      <Tooltip />
      <Bar dataKey="number_of_barks" fill="#82ca9d" />
    </BarChart>
      </ResponsiveContainer>
    </div>
  );
};

export default HourlyBarkChart;


I have tried to troubleshoot with my limited knowledge of REACT. The config of the code is similar to that of the WeeklyChart, which does work as expected.
Can anybody see why "onHourSelect" is not being recognized as a function when is is being passed as a prop?
I have tried to make the code very similar to code that does work, but no luck. I still see the prop being passed as undefined.
I am monitoring it with F12-console in my browser, which is where I got these log messages from.
